# no possible to make i18next work in Deno+Fresh Project

Tags: i18next, deno

I have a [Fresh](https://fresh.deno.dev/) project (1.4.2) and I try to add localization with [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/)

it works adding text from file but it does not work when I want to change the language by pressing a button.

When pressing `ChangeToSpanish` Button, title does not change to Spanish.

But when setting directly `i18n.changeLanguage("es")` (now commented in index.tsx) language changes to Spanish successfully.

configuration:

```
import i18next from "https://deno.land/x/i18next@v23.4.6/index.js";
import i18nextMiddleware from "https://deno.land/x/i18next_http_middleware@v3.3.2/index.js";


i18next
  .use(i18nextMiddleware.LanguageDetector)
  .init({
    debug: false,
    initImmediate: false,
    resources: {
      en: {
        translation: {
          home: {
            title: "Welcome To Fresh + i18next",
          },
        },
      },
      es: {
        translation: {
          home: {
            title: "Bienvenido a Fresh + i18next",
          },
        },
      },
    },
    fallbackLng: "en",
    preload: ["en", "es"],
  });

export const i18n = i18next;
export const middleware = i18nextMiddleware;
export const handle = i18nextMiddleware.handle(i18next);
```

implementation (index.tsx)

```
import { useSignal } from "@preact/signals";
import Counter from "../islands/Counter.tsx";
import { i18n } from "../i18next.ts";
import ChangeToSpanish from "../islands/ChangeToSpanish.tsx";

// i18n.changeLanguage("es");

export default function Home() {
  const count = useSignal(3);
  return (
    <div class="px-4 py-8 mx-auto bg-[#86efac]">
      <div class="max-w-screen-md mx-auto flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
        <img
          class="my-6"
          src="/logo.svg"
          width="128"
          height="128"
          alt="the Fresh logo: a sliced lemon dripping with juice"
        />
        <h1 class="text-4xl font-bold">{i18n.t("home.title")}</h1>
        <p class="my-4">
          Try updating this message in the
          <code class="mx-2">./routes/index.tsx</code> file, and refresh.
        </p>
        <Counter count={count} onClick={() => console.log("clicked!")} />
        <ChangeToSpanish />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

ChangeToSpanish.tsx

```
import { i18n } from "../i18next.ts";

export default function ChangeToSpanish() {
  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={() => {
        i18n.changeLanguage("es");
        console.log("changed language to Spanish");
      }}
    >
      Change Title to Spanish
    </button>
  );
}
```

The repo with the code with reference: https://github.com/datracka/deno-fresh-hello-world

What Am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: I believe routes don't support client-side JS? You'd need to move that into an island, as it'll just be static in your browser.

Comment: Hi @rschristian thanks for your help, I did try this approach but did not work. The issue is that changing the language does not trigger a re-render of the application / component. I added my findings as answer.

Comment: I'm similar that you. But I hve two problems:

1) When I change the languaje and I refresh the languaje continue in the option "fallbackLng", no save the change

2) If I want change to "es" I need use function `changeLanguage()` in **routers** and **islands** because each one if a different layer, otherwise the component in **islands** is in "en" and page in "es"

Answer (score 0):

After some research I'd like to post my findings for later consultancy in case anybody has same issue.

Problem was that setting the language does not "re-render" the view.

As Deno Fresh is a SSR framework I had 2 paths to try:

- To use [react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com/). I did not explore this path. `Preact`, the Fresh templating engine supports react packages using `compat` mode. Theoretically it should some how trigger a component re-render. What I don't know is, if this package is suitable for a pure SSR framework.
- To handle Fresh as a pure Server side application. It is what I did. Basically I pass as query parameter the language, and the application translates and renders the content based in the language set. When uses is changing the language, what I am doing is reloading the site. Maybe not the most elegant way, but it works.

Comment: Fresh is an islands framework, not a pure SSR framework. The issue is that you're not creating an island, so the component is server-only.

Comment: I'm same like you jajaja, I have that use one a simple <a> and refresh the web site :/